# How to use fluentbit in my Rails App to log to EFK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, elastic-stack, jruby, fluent-bit

I did some research to implement logging possibilities in my Rails App.
There are a lot of good blocks and gems description to use Logstash or fluentd to send my logs to ElasticSearch.

But so far I didn't find any documentation using fluentbit.
Did someone have experiences using this and can show a prope and basic way, how to implement it?

I am using either Ruby 2.7.x or Jruby like 9.2.20.0 and the latest Rails 6.1 Version.